# Gson dependency for grails

Tags: maven, grails, gson

Hello I have following GSON dependency in my BuildConfig.Grooovy file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

and these repos

```
repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenCentral()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()

        mavenRepo "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/"
}
```

This is a pretty basic question but I am getting following error and dont know how to fix it!

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact com.google.code.gson:gson:zip:2.2.4 in mavenCentral (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it looks like from the error message is that you have declared the dependency as a grails plugin inside plugins section.

```
//incorrect, hence it is looking for a .zip artifact instead of a .jar
plugins {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

instead add it as a dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Comment: It wasn't even 3am! That was a rookie